# How to handle boss's invitation to become a Facebook Friend knowing that sometimes my Friends might post something that is not work-appropriate

Tags: management, relationships, work-life-balance

I've had a pretty good working relationship with my boss for the past 1 1/2  years.  He trusts me to deal with the problems he gives me, I give him the best quality work that I can, occasionally there are some hangups but in general I do good work for him, he appreciates me, and we get along well in the office.

A short time ago, while I was at home, I noticed my boss's name on Facebook, as an invitation to become a Facebook Friend with him.

Now, I don't normally post racy or inappropriate things on my Facebook (I have my family to discourage me from doing that), and I don't usually post inflammatory work-related things on it either (because I  know better than to do that), but I am a bit of  a nerd and I don't know if my boss's political leaning is in-line with mine (I think it is, but it hasn't really come up).

Do I have anything to worry about?  Is it appropriate to accept this invitation?

Note that I don't ever go on Facebook during work, even during hours when nothing is really going on, because I know sometimes my Facebook Friends might post something that is not work-appropriate (again, nothing really racy or inappropriate, just inappropriate for a work environment).

Comment: The number of bad stories that result from friending your boss on Facebook vastly outnumber the good ones. :)

Comment: @Irwin True.  And I prefer to err on the side of caution, but I also don't want to 'snub' my boss, especially since he's a pretty cool guy.

Comment: You could add him but set him in a list that does not mix with your other friends, like "Acquaintances". I post almost exclusively to my "Friends except acquaintances" list. This does leave you at the whim of the Zuckerbeast when it decides to change the privacy settings for the nth time, though.

Comment: Facebook used to allow a certain amount of control over who got to see what on your profile/wall, and you could create groups of peers with different permissions. I'm not sure if this would help that. Another option which I know several people have chosen is to create two profiles, a "work" profile which they keep very modest and conservative and work/family friendly. They also have a more personal profile which is where all the "interesting" stuff is... ;)

Comment: Simply tell him that you like to keep your private and business interaction separate and that, as a matter of personal policy, you do not FB friend coworkers.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here, but just a point of note, it may be possible that Facebook is doing something funny here. Facebook has been known to do funny things with what they present users to see how they react ([as reported here](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/jun/29/facebook-users-emotions-news-feeds)). I might be extrapolating into nonsense, but it could be Facebook guessing a connection and trying to make it happen (a very similar thing happened to me once). Not saying this is the case here, but it's worth noting for others who might have a siilar situation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Friending your boss can indeed be a very bad idea.  Unless you are already actual friends who do things together outside of work, its bad form for him to have sent you the friend request in the first place and put you on the spot.

An approach to handling this is to thank him for the friend request, but tell him you'd prefer to keep your work life and home life separated online.  That will help assure him its not a personal problem you have with him.  If you use LinkedIn, that might be a better network to 'friend' him on.

Comment: Honestly, ignoring it until they asked about it probably would be the actual approach I took if this happened.

Comment: I think it's going to probably be my approach too...hooray for cowardice!  (better part of valor)

Comment: I have friends who keep a separate Facebook account for work friends. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: @DJClayworth That's a great idea. I have a "burner" Facebook account just so I have something to log into websites/mobile games without spamming my actual account but I never thought of having a "professional" account for reasons like this.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I'd like to point out that simply ignoring the request allows(at least at one point in the past) allowed the sender to view what you posted as if you were friends. Admittedly, I don't know if this is still the case but discussing it with your boss and then handling the request would be my recommendation. Don't let it sit in your inbox.

Comment: I have been in this situation myself. This is the approach I took myself. I first politely told him at the office that I had seen the request, but that I was going to decline, because I don't like to mix work with private life if I can avoid it. Then I declined. He was OK with that. In fact he later came back to me and told me my statement had got him thinking about this and he would stop inviting employees and would unfriend the ones that had already accepted. He actually did that the same day.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think this is a horrible idea: the simpler the better. If I have to split my accounts in two, I'd rather have none.

Comment: what is your problem with setting up appropriate privacy rules? I mean, for me it is more meaningful than having two accounts; and I can’t see why ‘acquaintancing’ (rather than friending) your boss could be a bad idea if acquaintances aren’t allowed to read most of posts on your wall (etc).

Comment: @törzsmókus Facebook keeps changing how the privacy settings work.  There's no guarantee that keeping an "acquaintance" list separate will _stay_ separate, and you're not likely to get a notification if the appropriate settings are removed/split/merged with other settings.

Comment: Upvoted because the Boss should be a linkedin contact, not a facebook one.  I've never heard of a good story related to friending a boss, or even a coworker, on facebook.

Comment: I'd say speak to your boss in person, let him know you're declining his Facebook friend request because you like to keep your work life and personal life separate, but that he's more than welcome to connect with you on LinkedIn (which is a professional network and thus suitable for such social connections). This way he (hopefully) understands that it's not about him, but about maintaining a separation between work and home.

Answer (score 8):

The best thing to do would be to add him to a list that you restrict access/visibility to.

I have had business acquaintances and other people I do not really know add me on facebook. I don't want people whom I don't know to see mine or my family's personal lives.

I am not worried about inappropriate posts or hiding anything, it's just getting too personal with people I am not personal with.

So adding them to different lists with different visibility permissions and being mindful when you post stuff of who you intend to share with.

Comment: +1 for this. I have a list called 'limited profile', which I restrict as much as possible. Whenever I get awkward friend requests such as this, I just add them to 'limited profile'。

Comment: there is also built-in "restricted" list offered by facebook. Using that list only thing showing is what is public anyway. It's a reasonable default, which I use for some family members.

Comment: Facebook has a history of changing their security controls and, at times, has fouled up by giving things more visibility than you had originally set them to.

Answer (score 7):

Be blunt. Tell your boss that you have friends and family who occasionally post stuff that would make a US Navy sailor blush and you don't want to expose him to that, especially since you are unwilling to pay the price of not letting your friends and family do their thing :) Don't make it more complicated than it actually is - just say "no" :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is related to what you are connecting, and how you know your boss.  If you know him socially, i.e. you spend time with him outside of work, you may consider connecting to him (but maybe worth pre-warning him about zany cousin Bob who should carry a parental warning sticker).

If your relationship is purely work related, I'd avoid Facebook, maybe offer to connect via Linkedin etc (although that can have its' own issues if you decide to look for a new job).

If he's already sent a request, I'd politely reply declining, but explaining that you're not snubbing him, but you do keep things separate (and maybe suggesting the alternate as above)

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn is for professional connections; Facebook is for friends and family.  Not only is adding your boss a bad idea for your job, it can be dangerous to your career and it was inappropriate for your boss to put you in the awkward position of having to make this decision.  You deserve to be comfortable and goofy on your personal Facebook page just as you would in the comfort of your own home--having your boss watching isn't conducive to this.

My suggestion would be to ignore the invite altogether.  I have invitations from people that have been sitting in my inbox for years.

If your boss follows up on the request, you may tell him/her that you are actually trying to pare down your friends list to only your closest friends and family as it is just becoming a big distraction for you otherwise.  You can welcome him to connect with you on LinkedIn.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That's it, you just lost your Job. (just joking)

isn't there any group option, that you can separate your boss from your normal friends and put some of your friends in that same group that you know they wont do anything stupid, maybe warn them that your boss is in there and check some security settings to see if you can block some options that may cause problems like posting on your wall.

If you don't accept your boss as a friend, it wont go down well.

If it bothers you that much, get out of Facebook book altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This has always been a tricky issue. On one hand, many people are averse to adding co-workers on Facebook per the reasons given above. But at the same time, things could become awkward if you reject someone's friend request. Suppose your manager is considering whether to give you a raise. If you declined his friend request, and he ultimately doesn't promote you, how do you know it's not because you "snubbed" him?

That said, I would recommend accepting his friend request, but only after making sure he can't see anything that would be inappropriate for work. Your manager isn't going to be able to access all the details of your private life just because you're connected, especially when you have the appropriate privacy settings in place. It's not so much who you connect with, but what you post and who you share it with.

I hope this helps.

Comment: why was this even downvoted?